# Addition in time value

Tags: c

I have created a program to add three hours in the local time of my country but the program is not giving the difference of three hours instead giving wrong date and time after addition. Kindly help me to identify to identify my mistake in the code.The output I get is following

1. 19/5/2020 2:27:50
2. 21/5/2020 14:27:50

```
#include <windows.h>
#define NSECS 60*60*60

int main()
{
    SYSTEMTIME st = {0};
    FILETIME ft = {0};

    GetLocalTime(&st);

    printf("%d/%d/%d %d:%02d:%d\n",
        st.wDay, st.wMonth, st.wYear, st.wHour, st.wMinute, st.wSecond);

    SystemTimeToFileTime(&st, &ft);

    ULARGE_INTEGER u = {0};

    memcpy(&u, &ft, sizeof(u));
    u.QuadPart += NSECS * 10000000LLU;
    memcpy(&ft, &u, sizeof(ft));

    FileTimeToSystemTime(&ft, &st);

    printf("%d/%d/%d %d:%02d:%d\n",
        st.wDay, st.wMonth, st.wYear, st.wHour, st.wMinute, st.wSecond);

    return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Be specific: what output do you want, and what output do you actually get? Give a concrete example.

Comment: Okay, you added the output you get. Now add a concrete example of the output you want.

Comment: Wait, I think this might be a trivial arithmetic error. It looks like you're adding 60 hours instead of 3 hours. Do you get what you want if you change `60*60*60` to 60*60*3`?